# Angular's ngIf statement breaks Capybara test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, capybara, capybara-webkit

My test suite breaks when adding an `ngIf` statement to a validation tag.

I have a div that shows error messages if a field is invalid. Before, these errors were shown at page load. Now I want to show the errors only after the user has interacted with the input field. Adding an `ngIf` statement seems perfect for this, but it breaks my test suite.

This is working perfectly:

```
<div data-ng-messages="userForm.name.$error">
    <!-- some input field... -->
</div>
```

With this tests get flaky and unreliable.

```
<div data-ng-messages="userForm.name.$error" data-ng-if="userForm.name.$touched">
    <!-- some input field... -->
</div>
```

For instance, one of my feature specs tries to fill in a form, submit and reload page to see if the values are persisted. This test is working perfectly without the `ngIf` statement, but now the page has the old (not updated) values on page reload. The controller method is not even called (for instance `UsersController#update` if it's an update form).

### Gems

- rspec-rails 3.4.2
- capybara 2.7.1
- capybara-webkit 1.11.1
- database_cleaner 1.5.3

### Update

Changing the if statement to `userForm.name.$dirty` makes tests pass more often... I guess some kind of race condition is introduced here and maybe because $dirty responds a bit faster, that will make tests pass more often...

### Update 2

I have tried [capybara-angular](https://rubygems.org/gems/capybara-angular) gem, described as *Stable integration tests for AngularJS with Capybara*. Unfortunately, I get a timeout failure every time I try to visit a page with the webkit driver. I've described my problem in an issue on that repository.

### Update 3

I have managed to make some more tests pass with help from [Unreliable/Flakey Capybara/AngularJS Integration Tests With Timing Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35567959/unreliable-flakey-capybara-angularjs-integration-tests-with-timing-issues). I read it before I wrote this question, but I did not get that solution to work until now. The idea is to hide part of the page where Angular should present data (it seems as if Capybara does not know it should wait for Angular to do its bindings). This solved some of my problems, but it is not the best solution since it gives a worse user experience (you can actually see that the form is hidden when the page is loaded, then it gets visible after half a second or something).

### Update 4

I managed to get the tests pass with help from [capybara-ng](https://github.com/kikonen/capybara-ng) gem, though I had to interact with Angular directly (like `ng_model('model.attribute').set('value')` to get it to work. A more elegant solution would be to find a way to wait for Angular to do its bindings.